# Jwplayer fullscreen is not working in android device

Tags: android, jwplayer

I have implemented Jwplayer view in pageadapter.The problem is when i clicked on fullscreen the player view switched into landscape mode with half screen.I have to show jwplayer as full screen in landscape mode.
https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo

Comment: did you define jwplayer height somewhere? xml or java?

Comment: jwplayer full screen is working only in linearlayout using layout weight.